# Converting an array of floating point numbers into an array of timestamps in PHP

Tags: php

I'm an absolute PHP newbie, however I do understand some basic JS and Ruby.

I've got an array like the below.

```
[7, 13.5, 15, 16.5, 24]
```

Each element is a number between 0 to 24 and it signifies a time instance in the day. 7 signifies 07:00:00, 13.5 signifies 13:30:00, etc.

I'm looking help converting the above array into the below array & changing 24 into 23:59:59.

```
[07:00:00, 13:30:00, 15:00:00, 16:30:00, 23:59:59]
```

the items in the original array will **always** be either a whole number or have a 5 after the decimal.

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far, at least share your try in `JS` or `Ruby` ?

Comment: How does `24` equal `23:59:59`?

Comment: how `13:00:00` is for `13.5`?

Comment: I haven't tried this in JS/Ruby, although I'm pretty certain I'd solve it in either of those two languages. I'm not familiar with PHP syntax/debugging just yet, hence the post. @SougataBose - apologies. I meant 13:30:00. I've fixed the op.

Comment: @catcon - It doesn't , but I need it to be in the output. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

One line solution, Use **gmdate** function and make it simple. e.g. https://implode.io/brPerL

$time = [7, 13.5, 15, 16.5, 24];

```
$out = [];

foreach($time as $item){
    if($item == 24){
        $out [] = '23:59:59';
    }else{
        $out [] = gmdate('H:i:s', floor($item * 3600));
    }

}

var_dump($out);


array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "07:00:00"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "13:30:00"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "15:00:00"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "16:30:00"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "23:59:59"
}
```

Comment: Dear Bira, `7` and `15` is becoming `00:00:00`

Comment: Fixed it now, check again

Answer (score 1):

The code uses `sprintf` function to format time.

```
<?php
$timeArr = [7, 13.5, 15, 16.5, 24];
echo '<pre>';
$timeArr = array_map('convertNumberToTime', $timeArr);
var_dump($timeArr);

function convertNumberToTime($time)
{
    if($time == 24){
        $hours = 23;
        $minutes = 59;
        $seconds = 59;
    } else {
        $hours = floor($time);
        $minutes = ($time-$hours) * 60;
        $seconds = 0;
    }
    $timeString = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
    return $timeString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime`, but it is restricted with `hour` and `minute`

```
<?php
$arr = [7, 13.5, 15, 16.5, 24];
$timeArr = [];
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
  if($v > 23.5){
    $v = "23.59.59";
  }else{
    $v = (int)$v + (($v - (int)$v)*6)/10; 
    $v = number_format($v,2);
  }
  echo date("H:i:s",strtotime($v))."\n";
}
?>
```

Live Demo : https://eval.in/1087973

Output :

```
07:00:00
13:30:00
15:00:00
16:30:00
23:59:59
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php

 $data=array(7, 13.5, 15, 16.5, 24);
 $timestamp=array();

 foreach ($data as $value) {
    $MM="00";
    $HH=$value;
    if(is_float($value)){
       $HH=substr($value, 0, -2);
       $MM="30";
    }
    if($HH<10)
       $HH="0".$HH;
    $TIME=$HH.":".$MM.":00";
    if($HH==24)
       $TIME="23:59:59";
    array_push($timestamp,$TIME);
}

var_dump($timestamp);

?>
```

output:

```
 array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "07:00:00"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "13:30:00"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "15:00:00"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "16:30:00"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "23:59:59"
}
```

Link: https://www.jdoodle.com/a/169l